# Extracting a whole word from a string search in powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have multiple files in a folder that have unique links. They contain words with domain names, links that are not in any particular order in the text files. For example:

```
From:mail.usn.tn.com , Transporder via: exo2.reg.nt.com , fj.ter.usa
```

I have been trying to use powershell to accomplish the following: Find words that contain ".com" then extract the whole word, so in this case it would extract the first two but not the last one.

I'm using this as my code

```
Get-ChildItem  -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern '^.com' | Select -ExpandProperty line | Set-Content "Output.txt"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem  -Filter *.txt | Select-String -Pattern '([a-z0-9.]+\.com)' -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value }
```

You can test it here: https://regex101.com/r/ojTzVX/1